# jaxb - Unable to unmarshall from XSD which included other xsd

Tags: jaxb, xsd

I have an XSD(copy-metainfo.xsd) that includes other XSD (test-component-types.xsd). I already generated artifacts from copy-metainfo, but I am trying to unmarshall from copy-metainfo.xsd by using jaxb api.

here is my xsd.

```
test-component-types.xsd

  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>

  <xs:schema
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    elementFormDefault="qualified">

    <xs:complexType name="testComponent">
        <xs:attribute name="type" type="testComponentType"/>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:simpleType name="testComponentType">
      <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:enumeration value="TYPE1"/>
        <xs:enumeration value="TYPE2"/>
      </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>

  </xs:schema>





copy-metainfo.xsd

<xs:schema
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    elementFormDefault="qualified"
    attributeFormDefault="unqualified"
    xmlns:test="http://xmlns.test.com/cie/test/copy-metainfo"
    targetNamespace="http://xmlns.test.com/cie/test/copy-metainfo">

    <xs:include schemaLocation="test-component-types.xsd"/>

    <xs:element name="copy-metainfos" type="test:copy-metainfos-type" />

     <xs:complexType name="copy-metainfos-type">
      <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="copy-metainfo" type="test:copy-metainfo" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>

     <xs:complexType name="copy-metainfo">
      <xs:sequence>
         <xs:element name="file-paths" type="test:FilePaths" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
      </xs:sequence>
      <xs:attribute name="test-type" type="test:testComponentType"/>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="FilePaths">
      <xs:sequence>
         <xs:element name="location" type="test:Location" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
      </xs:sequence>    
    </xs:complexType> 

    <xs:complexType name="Location">
        <xs:attribute name="src" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:complexType>


  </xs:schema>
```

When I try to unmarshall from copy-metainfo.xsd with the following code, I get an error. These XSDs are contained in a same jar.

```
  JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(new Class[]{CopyMetaInfos.class});

  SchemaFactory schemaFactory = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
  InputStream xsdStream = CopyMetaInfos.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(COPY_METAINFO_SCHEMA);
  StreamSource xsdSource = new StreamSource(xsdStream);
  Schema schema = schemaFactory.newSchema(xsdSource);
  Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
  unmarshaller.setSchema(schema);
  return (CopyMetaInfos) unmarshaller.unmarshal(is);
```

Error:

> org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 22; columnNumber: 64; src-resolve: Cannot resolve the name 'test:testComponentType' to a(n) 'type definition' component.

line 22 is ''.

This is a XML that I an trying to unmarshall from a jar:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<copy-metainfos xmlns="http://xmlns.test.com/cie/test/copy-metainfo">
    <copy-metainfo test-type="TYPE1">
        <file-paths>
            <location src="common"/>
        </file-paths>
    </copy-metainfo>
</copy-metainfos>
```

I verified that the XSDs are in the jar and 'COPY_METAINFO_SCHEMA' variable points to a correct location. If I specify testComponentType directly in the copy-metainfo.xsd instead of including test-component-types.xsd, then it works.

Is there anything wrong with the XSD or XML or java code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

XML is correct (semantically and syntactically), i validated it by [XMLSpear](http://www.donkeydevelopment.com/)

You must add all XSD to schema validator ..test-component-types.xsd and copy-metainfo.xsd

```
InputStream xsdStream = CopyMetaInfos.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(COPY_METAINFO_SCHEMA);
```

in this way you added only one XSD and missing the definition of `test:testComponentType`

```
  JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(new Class[]{CopyMetaInfos.class});
  SchemaFactory schemaFactory = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);

  //Source copy-metainfo.xsd
  InputStream xsdStream = CopyMetaInfos.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(COPY_METAINFO_SCHEMA);
  StreamSource xsdSource = new StreamSource(xsdStream);

  //Source test-component-types.xsd
  InputStream xsdStreamTest = CopyMetaInfos.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(TEST_COMPONENT_TYPES);
  StreamSource xsdSourceTest = new StreamSource(xsdStreamTest);

  Schema schema = schemaFactory.newSchema(new StreamSource[]{xsdSource,xsdSourceTest});

  Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
  unmarshaller.setSchema(schema);
  return (CopyMetaInfos) unmarshaller.unmarshal(is);
```