# Organizing XSDs in a JAR

Tags: java, xsd, jaxb

I have the following structure in a JAR:

- Products.xsd
- ProductCommonTypes.xsd
- /com

  - /foo

    - Products.class

When I do

```
schemaURL = Products.class.getClassLoader().getResource(schemaFile);
```

I see "Using schemaURL: jar:file:/C:/my.jar!/Products.xsd".  I think this is good.

Later, I try to create a Schema and get an exception stating *"Cannot resolve the name 'common:nonEmptyString' to a(n) 'type definition' component."*

I believe that the problem is that it is unable to find *common:nonEmptyString* (which is in *ProductCommonTypes.xsd*) but can not figure out how to fix it.

**Products.xsd**

```
  <xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
   xmlns:p="http://www.foo.com/Products"
   targetNamespace="http://www.foo.com/Products"
   xmlns:common="http://www.foo.com/ProductsCommonTypes"
   elementFormDefault="qualified">

   <xs:import schemaLocation="ProductsCommonTypes.xsd" 
      namespace="http://www.foo.com/ProductsCommonTypes"/>

   <xs:element name="products">
      <xs:complexType>
         <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="name" type="common:nonEmptyString" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
         </xs:sequence>
      </xs:complexType>
   </xs:element>

</xs:schema>
```

**ProductCommonTypes.xsd**

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  targetNamespace="http://www.foo.com/ProductsCommonTypes"
  xmlns="http://www.foo.com/ProductsCommonTypes" 
  elementFormDefault="qualified" >

   <xs:simpleType name="nonEmptyString">
      <xs:annotation>
         <xs:documentation>A type that will require a non-empty string value be present
         </xs:documentation>
      </xs:annotation>
      <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
         <xs:pattern value="(\s*[^\s]\s*)+"></xs:pattern>
      </xs:restriction>
   </xs:simpleType>

   <xs:simpleType name="url">
      <xs:annotation>
         <xs:documentation>A HTTP URL</xs:documentation>
      </xs:annotation>
      <xs:restriction base="xs:anyURI">
         <xs:pattern value="https?://.+"></xs:pattern>
      </xs:restriction>
   </xs:simpleType>
</xs:schema>
```

[[jaxb - Unable to unmarshall from XSD which included other xsd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26068773/jaxb-unable-to-unmarshall-from-xsd-which-included-other-xsd][1])
suggests adding all schema references, but I am working with many schemas that all import several other schemas.  Seems like it could get ugly quick!

1. Is there a generic/dynamic solution that does not require me to identify and hardcode all schemas everytime I plan on working with one that might import others?
2. I plan to move all XSDs to a *MyXSDs* folder within the jar at some point.  After moving them, will I have to do anything differently due to the location change?

Comment: I recommend that you move the solution from the "question" to an "answer" in order to reduce the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**

I was able to solve this using an [XMLCatalogResolver](https://xerces.apache.org/xerces2-j/javadocs/xerces2/org/apache/xerces/util/XMLCatalogResolver.html) and creating an [XML catalog](https://xerces.apache.org/xerces2-j/faq-xcatalogs.html) file.

I moved all of my XSDs into a single folder and have the following structure in my JAR:

- MyXSDs

  - Products.xsd
  - ProductCommonTypes.xsd
- /com

  - /foo

    - Products.class

First, I created the catalog file and identified the schema that was being referenced.

```
<!DOCTYPE catalog
    PUBLIC "-//OASIS//DTD Entity Resolution XML Catalog V1.0//EN"
           "http://www.oasis-open.org/committees/entity/release/1.0/catalog.dtd">
    <catalog xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:entity:xmlns:xml:catalog">

    <public
        publicId="http://www.foo.com/ProductCommonTypes"
        uri="ProductCommonTypes.xsd"/>

</catalog>
```

Then, I created an [XMLCatalogResolver](https://xerces.apache.org/xerces2-j/javadocs/xerces2/org/apache/xerces/util/XMLCatalogResolver.html) that uses my catalog file and used it as the ResourceResolver for my [SchemaFactory](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/validation/SchemaFactory.html).  It is important to note that the catalogs must be specified as *an ordered array of absolute URIs* as per the [constructor's documentation](http://xerces.apache.org/xerces2-j/javadocs/xerces2/org/apache/xerces/util/XMLCatalogResolver.html#XMLCatalogResolver(java.lang.String[])).

```
// The catalogs must be an ordered array list of *ABSOLUTE* URIs
String[] catalogs = new String[] { xmlCatalogAbsPath };
XMLCatalogResolver resourceResolver = new XMLCatalogResolver(catalogs);
schemaFactory.setResourceResolver(resourceResolver);
```

You must specify the **relative path** to the XSD file.  Therefore, because I put all of mine into a folder, I set *relatativeSchemaPath="MyXSDs/Products.xsd"* for use with [ClassLoader.getSystemResource](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getSystemResource(java.lang.String)).

```
StreamSource streamSource = new StreamSource(ClassLoader.getSystemResource(relatativeSchemaPath).toString());
Schema schema = schemaFactory.newSchema(streamSource);
```